# How to run Zend Project module...?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

**How to run Zend Project module...?**
This is my project folder structure.

**VIEW** at $APP_DIR/application/modules/catalog/views/scripts/item/display.phtml.

**CONTROLLER** at $APP_DIR/application/modules/catalog/controllers/ItemController.php

**BOOTSTRAP** at $APP_DIR/application/Bootstrap.php

**LAYOUT** at $APP_DIR/application/layouts/master.phtml

**FORM** at $APP_DIR/library/Square/Form/Contact.php

**AND LANGUAGE FILE** at $APP_DIR/languages/messages.fr.php:

Please what URL should I enter in browser URL section to run this project...
I want to run ItemController...
Please help me...

Comment: have you tried `http://[your base url]/catalog/item/`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that... It gives:An Error occurred. Page not found.

Comment: Is the .htaccess/url rewriting enabled (Otherwise you have to use the url like `http://[yourhost]/[path-to-public]/index.php/catalog/item/`? Are you using the standard router? Is the `indexAction` defined in your `ItemController`? Also: are you in `development` environment? If not could you change it - it will display a little bit more than just "Page not found".

Comment: the .htaccess/url rewriting enabled... i changed the environment to developement... using standerd router... indexAction is not defined in ItemController... I checked URL http://http://localhost/public/index.php/catalog/Item... but same thing is happening... :(

Comment: `indexAction` is not defined? It must be defined otherwise I get "Page not found" too. Are the "Request parameters" shown in the error message? Add them to your question, so we can see some details.

Comment: I defined IndexAction().

Comment: Now it is giving application error...  "Request parameters" are not there...

Comment: I guess you're still in `production` environment. But the application error is a good sign. You need to have a view for your `indexAction` (the name should be `modules/catalog/views/scripts/item/index.phtml`).

Comment: Thanks vstm...!   :) I done it...

Answer (score 0):

By default you URL would look like http://your_domain/catalog/item/display or, maybe, like http://your_domain/fr/catalog/item/display

Answer (score 0):

if your project is set up correctly you access a module like this:

- example.com/module/controller/action

**note:** take a look at this blog on how to set-up a modular ZF application:

- http://www.amazium.com/blog/create-modular-application-with-zend